# How to fix freeze in update documents mongoDb through C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I got some freeze in update documents in mongoDb through C#. What i need to do to fix it?

I have MongoDb collection with ~230000 documents. Signature is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5d4c3a086dad5e5ab8d397"),
    "Uid" : "SomeiDString",
    "SomeTextField" : "SomeText"
}
```

Indexes - two fields:

```
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "db.mycollection"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "Uid" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "Uid_1",
        "ns" : "db.mycollection",
        "background" : true
    }
```

In C# I make async operation `UpdateOneAsync`, with filter on `Uid` and update `SomeTextField`.

```
private async Task <bool> PutSomeTextMongoDb(string Uid, string SomeText)     {      
  var collection = database.GetCollection<User>(MONGO_DB_COLLEСTION);      
  var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("Uid", Uid);      
  var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set("SomeText", SomeText);      
  var option = new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true};      
  var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, option);
  return result.ModifiedCount != 0;    
}
```

Problem that I have: 5000 request got good avr time. Is about 2-3 ms. But some of them grow up to ~800-1000 ms... I know, it's only 5-6 long operation from 5k, but what is it? May be some locks for update operation, or when Mongo flush data i got some queue? mongostat and mongotop didn't answered me on this question...

Comment: You should use bulk operations, it's much better

Comment: @SimonMourier, unfortunately, i can't cash request and make multiply update, and can't "fire and forget", i need result of operation :c I found that update op can make global lock for documents, may be this is it